# accidently lowered font size of one of my i3 windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fonts, i3

While trying to come along with VIM I accidently lowered my font size of one of my windows in ´i3´. I could not find the proper shortcut to do so via google.
Can somebody tell me how to change font size via shortcuts within a window in ´i3´?

Comment: It hardly relates to i3 itself, but rather to the app in the window.
Is that terminal or gui app? Anyway Ctrl-+ is most common shortcut to increase font size in many apps, so it worth trying that

Comment: That worked - post as answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, that is not i3 specific question. Many applications provide following shortcuts to handle font size:

```
Ctrl - +  increase
Ctrl - -  decrease
Ctrl - 0  reset
```

(could not figure out how to make pretty-looking button-shaped shortcuts)